# Understanding subcriteria hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have the following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dp")
public class DailyProfit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Exchange.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="exchange_id")
    private Exchange exchange;
}
```

and I want to create a criteria query, such that it returns the result with all Exchanges having `id > 100`. Could I write just

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(DailyProfit.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("exchange.id", 100));
```

Instead of creating a sub-criteria like the following:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(DailyProfit.class).createCriteria("exchange", "ex");
criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("ex.id", 100));
```

Does hibernate allows us to do it that way? I tried this one and got some strange results which didn't look correctly. What does it actually do?

Comment: are  you looking for a way to get a criteria query with exchange.id to be graeter than 100? Or you are investigating possible different ways?

Comment: @giannisapi I'm investigating. It's not clear what the first example actually does. I thought they were equivalent...

Comment: stupid answer but why dont you print the sql code in the logs so that you see what query is getting executed each time?